# how to integration dynamic web fields and forms

Tags: web-development, javascript, rest

I'm trying to find a way to design backend that will be handling customized web forms creation on the fly. Once created those forms will be injected to part of the existing web pages.

I've created dynamic forms successfully but I'm unable to figure out how I can integrate these newly created forms or custom fields into my web pages to handle like posting data to some restful api most probably, or some unified interface that can handle all of the custom forms/fields?

I'm using backbonejs for my client side and for dynamic forms I'm using backbone.form plugin to create custom forms and fields on the fly. I'm persisting this on server. I've figured this part after a lot of RnD. I can show these forms and newly added fields to my already built forms on front end using backbone and presisted schema and data.

But problem is, there can be multiple forms and many fields; think of it as multi tabs. I need to device a workaround in a way that all of my forms can post data to some unified/common/generalized server route where I can manipulate it.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: i'm using backbonejs for my client side and for dynamic forms i'm using backbone.form plugin to create custom forms and fields on the fly. I'm presisting this on server. I've figured this part after a lot of RnD. I can show these forms and newly added fields to my already built forms on front end using backbone and presisted schema and data. But problem is there can be multiple forms and many fields; think of it as multi tabs. I need to device a workaround in a way that all of my forms can post data to some unified/common/generalized server route where I can manipulate it. hope this helps

Comment: @afr0 I still don't understand, can you write a short example code?